# Caption error with scrbook in combination with subfig

Tags: koma-script, subfloats, incompatibility, scrbook, subfig

I've recently updated the packages of my miktex distribution. Now I have a problem with the combination of KOMA script (scrbook) and the subfig package while compiling with LuaHBTeX.

The MWE gives me two errors about an "undefined control sequence". When I delete the subfig option `caption=false` it works. However, I use some KOMA options to change the appearance of the captions and I think I can remember that in this case the `caption=false` should be used.

What has changed since the previous versions I used?

- Subfig: Update `Package: subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package` to `not changed`
- scrbook: Update `Document Class: scrbook 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (book)` to `Document Class: scrbook 2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script document class (book)`

KOMA options for caption appearance:

```
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}
\newlength{\lengthforcapwidth}
\setlength{\lengthforcapwidth}{10pt}
\setcapwidth[c]{\textwidth - \lengthforcapwidth - \lengthforcapwidth}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass [] {scrbook}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[]%
        \centering%
        \subfloat[][Fig a]{%
            \label{subfig:Figa}%
            %\input{./Grafiken/TikzSource/FigaSource}}%
            }
        \hfill%
        \subfloat[][Fig b]{%
            \label{subfig:Figb}%
            %\input{./Grafiken/TikzSource/FigbSource}}%
            }
        \caption{A description}%
        \label{fig:notworking}%
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{caption}` to preamble isn't sufficent?

Comment: @ferahfeza I think the caption package and the internal Koma Script options to formatting captions clash. E.g. loading the caption package I get the warning `Package caption Warning: Ignoring optional argument [c] of \setcapwidth`

Comment: My TeXlive 2019 says : **Process exited normally**!!!

Comment: @C.F.G Thank you for the information, but I would like to stick to Miktex for the moment as I fear to make it even worse by switching the distribution. I wonder that no one else has encountered the same problem with Miktex so far. Koma script and subfig are quite common packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to replace package `subfig` by `subcaption`. Then you can use the options of packages `caption` and `subcaption` for the layout of the captions:

```latex
\documentclass [] {scrbook}

\usepackage{subcaption}% loads caption
\captionsetup[sub]{indention=0pt}

\captionsetup{
  font=small,
  labelfont={sf,bf},
  format=plain,
  indention=1em,
  margin=10pt
}

\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]%
  \centering
  \subfloat[][Fig a]{%
    \label{subfig:Figa}%
    \rule{5cm}{2cm}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[][Fig b]{%
    \label{subfig:Figb}%
    \rule{5cm}{2cm}%
  }%
  \caption{A description}
  \label{fig:notworking1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]%
  \centering%
  \subfloat[][Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.]
    {\label{subfig:Figc}\rule{5cm}{2cm}}%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[][Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.]
    {\label{subfig:Figd}\rule{5cm}{2cm}}%
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
    Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.}
  \label{fig:notworking2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use the KOMA-Script options:

```latex
\documentclass [] {scrbook}

\usepackage{subcaption}% loads caption
\captionsetup[sub]{indention=0pt}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}
\newlength{\lengthforcapwidth}
\setlength{\lengthforcapwidth}{10pt}
\setcapwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth - 2\lengthforcapwidth\relax}

\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]%
  \centering
  \subfloat[][Fig a]{%
    \label{subfig:Figa}%
    \rule{5cm}{2cm}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[][Fig b]{%
    \label{subfig:Figb}%
    \rule{5cm}{2cm}%
  }%
  \caption{A description}
  \label{fig:notworking1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]%
  \centering%
  \subfloat[][Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.]
    {\label{subfig:Figc}\rule{5cm}{2cm}}%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[][Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.]
    {\label{subfig:Figd}\rule{5cm}{2cm}}%
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
    Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.}
  \label{fig:notworking2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2020/07/22 v3.31 KOMA-Script package (type area)
subcaption.sty    2020/08/23 v1.3g Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2020/09/02 v3.5a Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/08/30 v2.0 caption3 kernel (AR)
caption-koma.sto    2020/08/22 v2.0 Adaption of the caption package to the KOMA
-Script document classes (AR)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2020-09-01 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 ***********
```